# ImageInspectError - When trying to start k8s pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am getting an error when I try to start my webserver pod for my k8s configuration:

```
Failed to inspect image "us.gcr.io/image-place/base-laravel-php71-supervisor-xdebug": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument
```

- This has come up literally out of no where after not touching my laptop all weekend.
- Googling has not come up with any solutions.
- Deleted the offending pod.
- I have restarted Kubernetes / Docker for Desktop.
- Restarted computer.

Environment:

- OSX 10.14.3
- Docker for Desktop  2.0.0.3 (31259)
- Kubernetes v1.10.11

Answer (score 2):

Now I feel silly because I should have thought of this sooner, but I will leave this answer incase someone comes across this issue in the future.

I ran:

`docker rmi us.gcr.io/image-place/base-laravel-php71-supervisor-xdebug`

deleted the offending pod and everything seems to be working fine.